# Three displays (1920x1200) with one graphics card

Tags: display, extended-desktop

I'm using a Zotac GTS250 with two 1920x1200 28" monitors in extended desktop mode.

I need an additional display, so I'm going to buy one more 1920x1200 28", but since GTS250 doesn't support more than two displays, I need a slight upgrade.

The best solution for me is a new graphics card - I'm thinking of an AMD 6850 XFX 1024MB, with two DVI, one HDMI and one DP. I don't need Eyefinity, I just need three displays with the same maximum resolution of 1920x1200 working in extended desktop mode. However I looked on the AMD website and found out that Eyefinity requires at least one display connected through DP, and there is no information about three displays *without Eyefinity*. Since my displays are DVI and HDMI only, I need a dongle, which is unavailable in my country and I don't have time to wait for its delivery.

Can I use the 6850 with three 1920x1200 displays, connected via DVI-DVI-HDMI? Is there any alternative solution in this situation (three DVI/HDMI displays)?

A second graphics card is not a solution currently because the second PCI-E port on my motherboard works in 1x mode. Would it be a possible solution to use two **different** graphics cards to solve my problem? I mean, I actually can buy a new motherboard if there is no chance to connect displays. As I said, DVI-DVI-HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

> However I looked on the AMD website and found out that Eyefinity requires at least one display connected through DP, and there is no information about three displays without Eyefinity.  I don't need Eyefinity, I just need three displays with the same maximum resolution of 1920x1200 working in extended desktop mode. However I looked on the AMD website and found out that Eyefinity requires at least one display connected through DP, and there is no information about three displays without Eyefinity.

That's because you can't power three displays with one card without Eyefinity.  Nor can you run three displays without using DP. With the 6850, it is impossible to use DVI - DVI- HDMI.

AFAIK, this is impossible with any mainstream card, simply because it is expensive to implement, and hardly anyone uses it.  You should look at Matrox cards, which allow three displays on one card.

Comment: What about two graphics cards?

Comment: Possible. Note: to keep Aero, both cards must use the same driver. If you mix a Nvidia and an AMD card, you'll lose Aero support.